# Assigning Multiple Values ​to a Variable in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables

```
const i = [1 || 2]
if (!message.channel.name.includes(o['opts' + i].identity.username.toLowerCase())) return message.channel.send('do commands only at <#bot-commands-id>');
console.log('oke');
```

How can I assign multiple values ​​to variable?

```
const i = [1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5]
```

as

Comment: You're looking for a loop and/or an array.

Comment: sort of can you answer

Comment: "*Sort of*"? Why not? Do you know what arrays and loops are already? What exactly do you want to do with the multiple values?

Comment: If those values ​​are equal, I want to open a channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to Use an array , and you do your condition with `i[index]` accessing all indexs with a for loop.

In your case is :

```js
const i = [1 ,2 ];
for (let j = 0 , j <= i.length , j++) {
   if (!message.channel.name.includes(o['opts' + i[j]].identity.username.toLowerCase())) return message.channel.send('do commands only at <#bot-commands-id>');
   console.log('oke');
}
```

Comment: Given how the `if` statement `return`s from the function, this is probably not what the OP wants

Comment: syntaxerror: identifier "j" has already been declared

Comment: if you alrdy used `j` as variable just change it to a unused name